# Creating a dynamic grid system on a webpage

Tags: php, html, css, grid-system

I'm looking to create a grid system for a webpage that I am working on to display a certain number of items/item properties. However, since the data I have is very dynamic, I won't always know the number of items that I need to display, and therefore won't know exactly what dimensions the grid items should have to format the page correctly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how I could start a grid like the one above?

I am somewhat familiar with HTML, php, and CSS.  I understand that there is a big resource of data for creating online, however I don't think I found what I was looking for.

Comment: Strongly I suggest you using css frameworks, they already spent lots of time to prepare a solution for these problems. Furthermore, they are easier to use and save you from a headache!

Comment: Thank you Maysam, I may very well look into different pre-existing frameworks, however, I would still like to know in theory how this would be done so that I can be able to make any changes needed

Comment: It's just **CSS**, for example you have a parent `<div>`, you assign a `width` to it, then for children, you can assign related width, like `10%`, `15%`, etc. it's how they work

Answer (score 0):

So you have a set of items, and for each item you have a number of properties? Presumably you have the same properties for each one?

That's tabular data. Use a [table](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#tabular-data).

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Item
            <th scope="col">Colour property
            <th scope="col">Size other
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Foo
            <td>Blue
            <td>XXL
        <tr>
            <td>Bar
            <td>Red
            <td>Small
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin, are you able to style tables in the same manner as divs?  I would've also thought a table would be ideal, but the names/properties of items would vary somewhat and I would want full control In styling them

Comment: Depends what you mean by "in the same manner" and "full control".

Comment: If you can use a table format, then you can extend much of the functionality and styling by using jQuery DataTables https://datatables.net/. Since your data is dynamic, the control can easily adjust to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS frameworks those support grid, like [UIKit](http://getuikit.com/docs/grid.html). 
You can use it like this:

```
<div class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-1-3">first</div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-3">second</div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-3">third</div>
</div>
```

UIKit supports up to 10 columns grid, from `uk-width-1-1` to `uk-width-1-10`

Comment: Also you can do some php tricks to make it more dynamic, like `<div class="uk-width-1-<?variable_column(); ?>">foo</div>`

Answer (score 0):

If your data is going to be dynamic [masonry jquery](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://masonry.desandro.com/&ei=4TYoU4ShL8b9rAf6Lw&usg=AFQjCNFsPVBwJgBCNJhxy-nuTA2bUedf_A&bvm=bv.62922401,d.bmk) can be great help to you. Check out its various features.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the HTML will look like:

```
<ul class="block-grid">
    <li><div></div></li>
    <li><div></div></li>
    <li><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

This is how you will make it work:

```
.block-grid {
   list-style-type: unstyled;
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   /* If you want 3 items in a row */
   margin-left: -2%;
}

.block-grid > li {
   /* If you want 3 items in a row */       
   margin-left: 2%; 
   width: 31.3%;
}
```

Change the calculation as per the number of items you want in one row.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps Javascript would be a better method to achieve this?